# Copyright for Speeding Photo

Tags: copyright, germany, speeding

If I get a ticket for speeding in Germany with a photo taken by an automatic camera, is there any copyright attached to that photo, or can I use it without asking the state for permission?

Comment: In the US the government works for the people.  It is difficult for me to imagine an entity that is subservient to the public, using a robotic device that was purchased with taxpayer funds, asserting a claim over an image that has no artistic or commercial value.  But then one should never underestimate the righteous zealotry of a bureaucracy:  https://reason.com/2019/01/02/judge-confirms-that-oregon-engineer-has/

Comment: @MichaelHall works of the US federal government are in the public domain in the US.

Comment: @phoog, what about state, county, or municipal government works?

Comment: @MichaelHall they are not excluded from copyright protection (so most traffic enforcement photos in the US would also enjoy copyright protection if a court found the photo to be a work of human authorship; however, the monkey selfie case suggests that courts would not make such a finding.)

Comment: J Fabian Meier: "is there any copyright attached to that photo, or can I use it without asking the state for permission?": The two possibilities are not mutually exclusive.  There are circumstances in which one can use copyright-protected material without the copyright holder's permission.  Therefore, even if the state does have copyright in that photo, you may be able to use it for certain purposes without the state's permission.  Since you haven't mentioned the use you have in mind, we can't address it specifically.

Answer (score 3):

A flash photo (Blitzfoto/Beweisfoto) is a technical aid (Technische Hilfsmittel) for the speed limit enforcement (Geschwindigkeitsüberwachung).

They are created for the **sole purpose** to be used as evidence for a fine notice (Bußgeldbescheid) and must originate from a responsible authority (i.e. not privat persons or companies) that is determined by state laws.

It is an integral portion of the file (Akte) of the notice. The file belongs to the responsible authority (generally called **Bußgeldstelle**).

Since it is a combination of technical data togeather with a photo, the copyright rules for a photo should not be assumed.

[image]

- flash photo of a culprit flying 15 km/h over the 30 km/h speed limit

The responsible authority will not have any copyright, due to [§5 UrhG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0033), but it still belongs to them.

---

**Sources**:

- Act on Copyright and Related Rights (Urheberrechtsgesetz – UrhG)

  - [§5 - Official works](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0033)
  - [§10 - Presumption of authorship or ownership](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0050)

Comment: I hope the culprit in your picture also gets fined for the missing lights and not using a seat belt.

Comment: @quarague Sorry, but thoses rules apply only to *Motor vehicles*. See my comment to this topic under my answer to: [Is it illegal to ride a drunk horse?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80432/is-it-illegal-to-ride-a-drunk-horse#comment173268_80434)

Comment: @quarague perhaps they can fine the culprit for violating civil aviation regulations.

Comment: @phoog Doubts were expressed from 'officialdom' that even if found that the €25 fine could not be paid. So the matter was closed due to it being disproportionate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson what happens to a human who cannot pay a fine of this sort?

Comment: @phoog A human is responsible for their actions, an animal is not. At present a jail term in days could be determined based on their income in cases that accumilate due to multible accourdances. This law is presently being reviewed.

Comment: Thanks.  So in the humorous context of pretending that pigeons can be held to account by the law, we can say that the pigeon might be sent to jail (or the zoo?).  I am sure that the society for animal protection will have something to say about that.

Comment: @phoog [2023-03-15: Gesetzentwurf: Weniger Haft für nicht gezahlte Geldstrafen | tagesschau.de](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/gesellschaft/faq-ersatzfreiheitsstrafen-101.html)

Comment: What exactly is the effect of "but it still belongs to them"? Can I use such a photo freely, or not?

Answer (score 1):

### It’s possible there is no [copyright](https://www.sydney.edu.au/content/dam/corporate/documents/sydney-law-school/research/publications/slrv43n2jun2021mccutcheonfinal.pdf)

I’m not familiar with the specifics of German copyright law, but, in general, a photograph must have an author to be protected by copyright.

As far as I know, it has not been litigated but it’s possible that a photo taken by an automated camera has no author and, therefore, no copyright.

A counter argument is that the technician who set up the camera, choosing its field of view and the parameters by which it is triggered is sufficient to make them the author.

Assuming that is the case, then the technician owns the copyright and the person who engaged the technician has full economic rights. Unlike English speaking countries, copyright in [Germany](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=bbc74ca2-448d-40bd-bfe8-dbbae104964a#:%7E:text=May%20an%20employer%20own%20a,the%20owner%20of%20the%20copyright.) does not recognise the “work for hire” doctrine and does not allow transfer of copyright except by inheritance.

So, you would need the technician’s permission to use it and the states permission to profit from it. Subject to the normal exceptions.

Comment: This is doubtfull. A Speeding Photo (Blitzfoto) is an integral portion (evidence) of the fine notice (Bußgeldbescheids) issued by the responsible authority (Bußgeldbehörde). That authority would be the creator (Urheber) of the document and since their name is on the notice fullfils the condition of [§10 - Presumption of authorship or ownership - Act on Copyright and Related Rights (Urheberrechtsgesetz – UrhG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_urhg/englisch_urhg.html#p0050). So it may very well protected.

Comment: @MarkJohnson they can claim copyright but they don’t have it unless there is a human author which is doubtful. In any even, an organization in Germany cannot own copyright (except through a bequest) because German copyright is not transferable

Comment: Interesting. I would have guessed that there is some precedent for "automatic" cameras, like e.g. surveillance cameras.

Comment: See **§5 Official works** in the above link. My doubts were about the *technician’s permission* of your answer.

Comment: if you have an exclusive license, you do *not* need author's allowance in germany.

Comment: §5 UrhG (1) Acts, statutory instruments, official decrees and **official notices**, as well as decisions and official head notes of decisions do not enjoy copyright protection. - The speeding ticket is an official notice of a fine.

Comment: @Trish but the photograph was created independently of the official notice before the official notice existed.  It was the evidence upon which the official notice was based.  The fact that it was included along with the official notice does not turn it itself into an official notice.

Comment: In the end, if there is no copyright on the photo, then the government has the right to copy it, use it as evidence and send you a fine. The only difference is that you have a right to copy it as well.

Comment: [Something similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_selfie_copyright_dispute) was settled in the US by litigation in a federal court, but you shouldn't assume a German court will decide the same way. At least put a US tag on the answer.